# Celery, RabbitMQ, Redis: Celery message enters exchange, but not queue?

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using Python 2.7 (sigh), celery==3.1.19, librabbitmq==1.6.1, rabbitmq-server-3.5.6-1.noarch, and redis 2.8.24 (from redis-cli info).

I'm attempting to send a message from a celery producer to a celery consumer, and obtain the result back in the producer.  There is 1 producer and 1 consumer, but 2 rabbitmq's (as brokers) and 1 redis (for results) in between.

The problem I'm facing is:

1. In the consumer, I get back get an AsyncResult via async_result =
   ZipUp.delay(unique_directory), but async_result.ready() never
   returns True (at least for 9 seconds it doesn't) - even for a
   consumer task that does essentially nothing but return a string.
2. I can see, in the rabbitmq management web interface, my message
   being received by the rabbitmq exchange, but it doesn't show up in
   the corresponding rabbitmq queue.  Also, a log message sent by the
   very beginning of the ZipUp task doesn't appear to be getting
   logged.

Things work if I don't try to get a result back from the AsyncResult!  But I'm kinda hoping to get the result of the call - it's useful :).

Below are configuration specifics.

We're setting up Celery as follows for returns:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://%s' % _SHARED_WRITE_CACHE_HOST_INTERNAL
CELERY_RESULT = Celery('TEST', broker=CELERY_BROKER)
CELERY_RESULT.conf.update(
    BROKER_HEARTBEAT=60,
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND,
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=100,
    CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=False,
    CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT=False,
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    )
```

We have another Celery configuration that doesn't expect a return value, and that works - in the same program.  It looks like:

```
CELERY = Celery('TEST', broker=CELERY_BROKER)
CELERY.conf.update(
   BROKER_HEARTBEAT=60,
   CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=CELERY_BROKER,
   CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=100,
   CELERY_STORE_ERRORS_EVEN_IF_IGNORED=False,
   CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=True,
   CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
   CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
   CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
   )
```

The celery producer's stub looks like:

```
@CELERY_RESULT.task(name='ZipUp', exchange='cognition.workflow.ZipUp_%s' % INTERNAL_VERSION)
def ZipUp(directory): # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    """ Task stub """
    _unused_directory = directory
    raise NotImplementedError
```

It's been mentioned that using queue= instead of exchange= in this stub would be simpler.  Can anyone confirm that (I googled but found exactly nothing on the topic)?  Apparently you can just use queue= unless you want to use fanout or something fancy like that, since not all celery backends have the concept of an exchange.

Anyway, the celery consumer starts out with:

```
@task(queue='cognition.workflow.ZipUp_%s' % INTERNAL_VERSION, name='ZipUp')
@StatsInstrument('workflow.ZipUp')
def ZipUp(directory): # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    '''
    Zip all files in directory, password protected, and return the pathname of the new zip archive.
    :param directory Directory to zip
    '''
    try:
        LOGGER.info('zipping up {}'.format(directory))
```

But "zipping up" doesn't get logged anywhere.  I searched every (disk-backed) file on the celery server for that string, and got two hits: /usr/bin/zip, and my celery task's code - and no log messages.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that using the following task stub in the producer solved the problem:

```
@CELERY_RESULT.task(name='ZipUp', queue='cognition.workflow.ZipUp_%s' % INTERNAL_VERSION)
def ZipUp(directory): # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    """ Task stub """
    _unused_directory = directory
    raise NotImplementedError
```

In short, it's using queue= instead of exchange= .